# Select all countries code gives 'We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email.' error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, countries

I have created a file for displaying all countries, but it shows `We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email.`

Please help me to fix the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

**app\design\frontend\Vendor\Module\Magento_Cms\templates\countryselect.ptml**

```
<?php
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$countryHelper = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country'); 
$countryFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory');

$countries = $countryHelper->toOptionArray(); //Load an array of countries

    foreach ( $countries as $countryKey => $country ) {

        if ( $country['value'] != '' ) { //Ignore the first (empty) value

            $stateArray = $countryFactory->create()->setId(
                $country['value']
            )->getLoadedRegionCollection()->toOptionArray(); //Get all regions for the given ISO country code

            if ( count($stateArray) > 0 ) { //Again ignore empty values
                $countries[$countryKey]['states'] = $stateArray;
            }

        }
    }

var_dump($countries);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried after clear cache and static content deploy ?

Comment: Yes.. but, that do not solve the issue...

Comment: try with apply 777 permission to /pub directory also

Comment: pub directory already has 777 permission.

Comment: Read more: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1549

Comment: I don't have this issue by default. It only appears when writing code for displaying countries.